# Android/Java How can I dynamically create cards using java?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app, that takes strings from a database and displays them in a list, and I would like each entry to be a specific card, like in Google Now.

The code I have to create the TextView is below:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Peixoto2Go", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Database db = new Database(this);
    TextView totalTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTipText);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
    totalTip.setText("Total Tip: $" + df.format(prefs.getFloat("totalTip", (float) 0.00)));
    int index = prefs.getInt("IDo", 0);
    View orderList = findViewById(R.id.orderList);
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++) {
        TextView order = new TextView(this);
        order.setText(db.getOrder(i));
        order.setPadding(30,30,30,30);
        order.setTextSize(22);
        order.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((LinearLayout) orderList).addView(order);
    }
```

What is the best way to modify it such that each time the for loop does its thing, the created view is a separate card?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards

Comment: You need to create a xml layout using android.support.v7.widget.CardView. Flatten the layout on every loop execution, and add your contents in the cardview. Please see if you can use a recycler view or viewholder pattern in your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve something similar to Google now, what you basically need is a Custom ListView.
To do so fist you need to implement a custom adapter(BaseAdapter) and then inflate a custom layout for each row using the adapter.

[Here is a good tutorial on how to create Custom ListViews](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

And do **remember**, its a good practice to use ViewHolders in ListViews to improve the performance of the ListView. [Click here to get more information on ViewHolders.](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)